# Handler.handleMessage is not called in test, but is called in the app

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-testing, android-handler

I have a service that runs in a separate process. The service spawns a new thread in `onCreate()` method. This thread sends messages back to the service.

If I start the app manually everything works fine - messages are received by the `Handler` in my service. But in my test `handleMessage()` method is never get called.

How can I fix my test to make `handleMessage()` method work?

Thanks!

**Service:**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private ServiceHandler mHandler;
    private final int MSG_HELLO_WORLD = 1;

    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d(TAG, "MyService.onCreate");
        super.onCreate();

        mHandler = new ServiceHandler();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Thread: run()");

                while (true) {

                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "sleeping...");
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Thread was interrupted.");
                        break;
                    }

                    Log.d(TAG, "sending message...");
                    Message msg = Message.obtain(mHandler, MSG_HELLO_WORLD);
                    msg.sendToTarget();
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "MyService.onStartCommand");
        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    private class ServiceHandler extends Handler {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ServiceHandler.handleMessage");

            if (msg.what == MSG_HELLO_WORLD) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Hello World message received!");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Test:**

```
public class MyServiceTest extends ServiceTestCase<MyService> {

    private static final String TAG = MyService.class.getSimpleName();

    public MyServiceTest() {
        super(MyService.class);
    }


    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
    }


    public void testStartService() throws Exception {

        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(getContext(), MyService.class);

        startService(startServiceIntent);

        MyService myService = getService();

        assertNotNull(myService);

        // give the service some time to send messages
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

App's logcat output (`handleMessage()` is called):

```
MyService.onCreate
MyService.onStartCommand
Thread: run()
sleeping...
sending message...
sleeping...
ServiceHandler.handleMessage
Hello World message received!
sending message...
sleeping...
```

Test's logcat output (`handleMessage()` is not called):

```
MyService.onCreate
MyService.onStartCommand
Thread: run()
sleeping...
sending message...
sleeping...
sending message...
sleeping...
sending message...
sleeping...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Your question seemed interesting to me, so I started digging*.

> If I start the app manually everything works fine - messages are received by the `Handler` in my service.

When you initialize `mHandler` in the `MyService`'s `onCreate()` method with `mHandler = new ServiceHandler()`, the [`Handler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) is associated with the message queue of the currently executed thread. `mHandler` process [`Messages`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html) from the queue that, in its turn, is handled by [`Looper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) which [**is looping**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#loop()). As the result you can see *"Hello World message received!"* in logs.

> But in my test `handleMessage()` method is never get called.

When you test the service its methods are called on `InstrumentationThread` (see the threads in `Debugger`) whose `Looper` is [prepared](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#prepare()) but **not looping**, so the messages can't be handled and aren't shown in logs.

> How can I fix my test to make handleMessage() method work?

I'd suggest the following options:

- ***Tie `MyServiceTest` to the thread on which `MyService`'s methods are called***. Write one more `unit test` for the component and then combine the test with `MyServiceTest` in one common `.java` test file. This will show the desired `logcat` output.
- ***Loop the prepared `Looper` of `InstrumentationThread` in `MyServiceTest`***. You can do it by adding `Looper.loop()` in the `testStartService()` method of `MyServiceTest`:

  ```
  public void testStartService() throws Exception {

      Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(getContext(), MyService.class);
      startService(startServiceIntent);
      MyService myService = getService();
      assertNotNull(myService);

      // Run the Looper (this call is to be added)
      Looper.loop();

      Thread.sleep(10000);
  }
  ```

  **Note**: running the `Looper` will show the desired `logcat` output, but the test won't stop because of `Looper.loop()` running indefinitely until you call [`Looper.quit()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#quit()).